# Visual C++ Build / Debugging Issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, build

I'm having a weird problem with Visual Studio. Whenever I change my code and build, even though I get the notification that the built was successful (and if any, it also shows errors in code and doesn't build) the executable is actually the previous build. This is getting really annoying and frustrating.

If I put a breakpoint on the new lines, the breakpoint gets disabled and it says

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is
>   associated with this line. Possible causes include: preprocessor
>   directive or compiler/linker optimization

If I put a breakpoint on old lines of code, it stops processing but shows me this message

> The source is different from when the module was built. Would you like
>   the debugger to use it anyway?

I never had this problem before and the source code in on my laptop's hard drive. It saves right away. The only way to get around this to `Clean` the entire solution manually every time, instead of basically pressing F5.

Comment: What exactly gets built? Is it the object files but not the executable for example? If so then check the time stamps on source, object, and executable before and after a build and let us know what they are. Also, what are they after a clean build?

Comment: Can you verify if you haven't opened a single source file multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for their suggestions. My mistake was that I defined the classes inside `.cpp` files, this somehow caused the linker to do weird (caching probably) stuff and link the old objects. I renamed the file to `.h` and everything's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your code is not built, or is built in a way you don't expect.

You might check by inserting a `#error foobar` preprocessor directive somewhere. If no error shows when building, you know you are in trouble!

But I never used Visual Studio (I'm only using Linux) so I cannot help more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using source files from another project (ex: if you are using a dll say, my.dll (which was built using some source files say, mycpp.cpp ); in your current project).
When you debugged into the file (mycpp.cpp), maybe you modified it.

Hence you need to rebuild the dll (my.dll) first in the project in which you created my.dll .
Or
Maybe you have opened a instance of mycpp.cpp in a window & debugging in another window.
you should rebuild the dll.

If you are not using files from another project, then I cant guess the cause...but still I would recommend using **rebuild** rather than **clean** & **build**.

please clarify your Question a bit.
@David expecting a reply from you...

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you have set main project some other project and building that.
make your project that you want to work on as "Main Project " by set main project available in menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to this issue since I was also stuck with it.  A colleague of mine just gave me a solution that works.  Yes, it seems really stupid, but it did the trick for me.

Our solution has many projects.  He told me to select the project that I wish to break into and set it as the startup project (right-click on the project name and pick "Set as startup project").  I was desperate, so I tried.  To my amazement, it works.

Since I have this window opened, I thought I'd share it in case someone else is stuck with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. But reason was not as yours.
Then I just restarted the visual studio and it ran as expected.